# I want to find column name in my database - is it possible?

Tags: sql-server, system-views

My database name is `CARE_DynamicsAX` and I want to find a column name `workerStatus`

Comment: Re-tagged with `sql-server` based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are trying to find the Table where you have a column name as `workerStatus`. If that is the case, you might run this query to find the same.

This works for the column names from TABLES for SQL Server.

This query would run under the assumption that you know that the column name that you are searching starts with `workerStat`

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE 'workerStat%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'workerStatus'
```